# How can I implement a hover on image to show a larger same image from the api

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have already been able to render photos from unsplash into the screen using react hooks and components.
What I want to implement next is on hover on any image I get a bigger sized image of it from the api.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import ImageList from '../ImageList/ImageList';
import './SearchPage.css';

const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY;

const SearchPage = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  const fetchImages = () => {
    axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos', {
      params: { query: searchText },
      headers: {
        Authorization: API_KEY,
      },
    })
      .then((data) => {
        setImage(data.data.results);
        setIsLoaded(false);
      });
  };

  const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchImages();
    setIsLoaded(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar
        className="search-bar"
        onSubmitHandler={onSubmitHandler}
        onInputChange={onInputChange}
        searchText={searchText}
      />
      <div className="image-container">
        {image && <ImageList image={image} isLoaded={isLoaded} />}
      </div>
    </div>

  );
};
export default SearchPage;
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';
import './ImageList.css';

const ImageList = ({ image, isLoaded }) => {
  if (isLoaded) {
    return (
      <div className="spinner">
        <ReactLoading type="spin" color="blue" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  const imgs = image.map(img => (
    <img
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.small}
    />

  ));

  if (imgs.length === 0) {
    return (
      <p>No images</p>
    );
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {imgs}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ImageList;
```

I will post some code to show.
So basically what I want is when I hover on img it should render on top of it a bigger version got from the api where he can download, and also show who the author of the photo is plus clickable to go to the original image in unsplash

Comment: On mouse over and mouse move, you will have to define a view port on image and based on the ratio, draw same section of image on  canvas. Simple! right???

Comment: Not really. If I can get more info